# How does Blockchain handle physical properties that can be broken down?

Tags: blockchain

Let's take a parcel of land, 1 hectare large, and I have this already registered to myself on the blockchain. How will this be done and at what granularity? In the future I could sell this an acre each or even at a square foot. Will there be a minimal granularity that is decided? Also, how is additional information stored - like what is the specific location/address/lat-long at which this property is and what are its dimensions?

Similarly for other things like a car. If I have a blockchain confirmed ownership of a car, what if I only want to sell off one of the tyres to somebody else? How will I potentially transfer ownership of only one tyre?

Not sure if the question is relevant, but I'm unable to get my head around this qn.

Comment: The answer is: any way you like. These are all things for you to decide on, and to implement in your smart contracts. There are presumably many ways to do these things - the question is too general/broad.

Comment: http://chromaway.com/papers/A-blockchain-based-property-registry.pdf  This paper had some good relevant points in case somebody else has this question.  Points about having an external registry and using contracts.